# urllib.urlretrieve is failing

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to download data using commands below.

```
import urllib
url = 'http://www.nse-india.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2002/MAR/cm01MAR2002bhav.csv.zip'
urllib.urlretrieve(url, 'myzip')
```

What I see in the file generated file my.zip is,

```
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;nse&#45;india&#46;com&#47;content&#47;historical&#47;EQUITIES&#47;2002&#47;MAR&#47;cm01MAR2002bhav&#46;csv&#46;zip" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;7d427b5c&#46;1311889977&#46;25329891
```

But I'm able to download the file from the website without any problem.
What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use `urllib2` and set the `user-agent` header to something it recognizes. It might just be blocking anything that doesn't appear to be a normal user.

Comment: Tried with user-agent as in Mozilla and still have the same problem, and I tried using [link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572202-web-browser-emulator/) and now file is downloaded but with extra bytes and it is kind of corrupted.

Comment: Try using the other headers from that recipe but not the code.